# How to implement maximum likelihood estimation with empirical likelihood

Tags: pytorch, jax

I am interested in the empirical likelihood approach.

While I found this paper describing a nested coordinate descent to deal with empirical likelihood https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00949655.2013.770514?needAccess=true , I wonder if there is a pytorch or Jax implementation from which I can learn details of how to use empirical likelihood in typical machine learning settings (e.g. for a regression problem where I do not want to specify a parameteic likelihood model).

I searched for example implementations but could not find any

Comment: I can't have access to the paper so I can't help you sorry

Comment: Hello Valentin. any implementation of an empirical likelihood based loss for a regression would be fine for me (regardless of the paper)

Comment: I don't know what it is exactly but this one seems to be the most related code I found after some research (in pytorch): https://github.com/HeinerKremer/Functional-GEL/blob/main/fgel/generalized_el.py#L15. I hope it can help you